# Remove this specific string from string

Tags: java, string, replace

I have following code to remove index.php occurrences from my string:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\"index\\.php\\?[^\"]*[;?]+id=([0-9]+)[^\"]*\\\"");
    String str = "1 serving Well-Seasoned Oven Roasted Pork Tenderloin<a href=\"index.php?option=com_recipe&amp;Itemid=101&amp;r=794\"> (recipe)</a><br />1 serving Parsley Garlic Potatoes <a href=\"index.php?option=com_recipe&amp;Itemid=101&amp;r=668\">(recipe)</a><br />\n</div>";

    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while(m.find()) {
        try {
            String match = m.group();
            str = str.replaceAll(match, "abc.html");
            p.matcher(str);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.printf("final:" + str);
```

First I want to get this "index.php?option=com_recipe&Itemid=101" and then get item id value.

Thanks

Comment: I don't get your question. If you're just wanting to replace "index.php" with "abc.html", wouldn't a simple non-regex find and replace be sufficient?

Comment: Isn't that what you're doing already?

Comment: I want to replace whole <a href="">, href url to abc.html

Comment: so, do you want this as result:    final:1 serving Well-Seasoned Oven Roasted Pork Tenderloinabc.html (recipe)</a><br />1 serving Parsley Garlic Potatoes abc.html(recipe)</a><br />
</div> ? Please can you post the result you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jsoup library and fixed it, following is my code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(data);
Elements elements = doc.select("a");
for(Element element: elements){
     String href = element.attr("href");
     data = data.replace(href, "abc.html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Changes made] How about following:

```
    String str = "1 serving Well-Seasoned Oven Roasted Pork Tenderloin<a href=\"index.php?option=com_recipe&amp;Itemid=101&amp;r=794\"> (recipe)</a><br />1 serving Parsley Garlic Potatoes <a href=\"index.php?option=com_recipe&amp;Itemid=101&amp;r=668\">(recipe)</a><br />\n</div>";
    str = str.replaceAll("\\<a.*?\\</a>", "<a href=\\\\\"abc.html>(recipe)</a>");
    System.out.printf("final:" + str);
```

Comment: Should be [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-), not [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), if you're not using regular expressions.

Comment: I want to replace whole <a href="">, href url to abc.html

Answer (score 0):

This should do the replace all occurences:

```
 str = str.replaceAll("index.php", "abc.html");
```

Why do you use pattern here?

Comment: Should be [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-), not [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), if you're not using regular expressions.

Comment: I want to replace whole <a href="">, href url to abc.html

Comment: @khelwood the above replaceAll changes all the occurrence of index.php.

Comment: @Vijay No, that's what `replace` does. `replaceAll` with change all occurrences of the _regular expression_ `"index.php"`, which is not what you mean to do.

Comment: @khelwood tried that out and found replace is sufficient here.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String str = "1 serving Well-Seasoned Oven Roasted Pork Tenderloin<a href=\"index.php?option=com_recipe&amp;Itemid=101&amp;r=794\"> (recipe)</a><br />1 serving Parsley Garlic Potatoes <a href=\"index.php?option=com_recipe&amp;Itemid=101&amp;r=668\">(recipe)</a><br />\n</div>";
 str = str.replaceAll("<a href=\"index.php.*?>", "<a href=\"abc.html\">");
 System.out.printf("final:" + str);
```

output:

```
final:1 serving Well-Seasoned Oven Roasted Pork Tenderloin<a href="abc.html"> (recipe)</a><br />1 serving Parsley Garlic Potatoes <a href="abc.html">(recipe)</a><br />
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape the dot in "index.php".